# if (!someArray[i])

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple question for C.
What does this statement mean?

```
 if (!someArray[i])
```

I know that the operator ! means NOT. But i cannot get my head around it.
Thank you!!

Comment: What's the type of someArray? Pointers?

Comment: @John OK, but if it's a null pointer check (as I'd expect) then we could give him a pointer-centric answer which might be more useful to him.

Comment: @John: someArray can be an array of objects with overloaded operator!, so it does matter.

Comment: @Maxim:  True enough, comment removed

Answer (score 7):

`if (!someArray[i])` means if `someArray[i]` is zero (or convertible to false) then the code inside the `if` block will be executed, otherwise it will not be executed!

If `someArray[i]` is not convertible to boolean value  OR if the *type* of `someArray[i]` doesn't define the operator `!` returning boolean value (or a value convertible to it), then your code will not compile.

Note: all numbers (int, float, double, char, etc) and pointers of any type, are convertible to boolean value.

Comment: Not true.. at least imprecise. `someArray[i]` doesn't need to be convertible to boolean at all - but it needs to handle the `operator!` and the result of it must be convertible to boolean.

Comment: @Kos : true. I agree. I hope the questioner will read this comment of yours.

Comment: @Kos:  you could incorporate the comment in to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C, it's equivalent to writing

```
if (someArray[i] == 0)
```

From the C language standard ([n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**
> **Constraints**
> 1 The operand of the unary `+` or `-` operator shall have arithmetic type; of the `~` operator, integer type; of the `!` operator, scalar type.
> **Semantics**
> ...
> 5 The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

As Kos and John Dibling pointed out, the situation in C++ is different.  From the latest C++ draft ([n1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf))

> **5.3.1 Unary operators**
> ...
> 8 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is implicitly converted to `bool` (clause 4); its value is `true` if the converted operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. The type of the result is `bool`.

Comment: Nope. It's not equivalent in C++ for class objects.

Comment: -1:  This is incorrect in too many cases for this to be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Kos: the OP explicitly mentioned C, not C++. @John Dibling: &sect; 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators, &para; 5: "The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`."

Comment: @John Bode, the OP tagged this question both C and C++, equally explicitly. At least edit the answer to indicate that it's only equivalent in C.

Comment: @JohnBode, Great! +1 for the source.

Comment: I think that for the OP's apparent experience level, this is probably the most understandable and useful answer.  I think that rather than adding "In C", I might add something like "(unless `somearray[i]` is a type in C++ where `operator!()` applies and does something unusual, which should be rare)".

Answer (score 1):

It means simply that if the value in someArray[i] is interpreted as false (either a zero value, or boolean false), then the code will enter the if block.

Assume the following uncompiled/untested code:

```
//we make an array with some chars, but have one as NULL (0)
char someArray[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 'e' };

//we loop through the array using i as the index
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    if(!someArray[i]) //if this entry is null (0) or false, show an error:
    {
        printf("%d does not have a char!\n", i);
    }
    else //otherwise, print the contents
    {
        printf("%d is %c\n", i, someArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Expected output would be:

- 0 is a
- 1 is b
- 2 is c
- 3 does not have a char!
- 4 is e

Answer (score 1):

The `!` (not) operator will return `true` if the expression evaluates to a 0.  So:

```
class SomeObject
{
}; // eo class SomeObject

std::vector<int> intVector;
std::vector<long> longVector;
std::vector<SomeObject*> objectVector;

intVector.push_back(1);
intVector.push_back(0);

longVector.push_back(4049);
longVector.push_back(0);

objectVector.push_back(new SomeObject);
objectVector.push_back(NULL); // or nullptr if you're on C++0x, or even just 0!


if(!intVector[0])
{
    // false, intVector[0] is not zero.
}

if(!intVector[1])
{
    // true!  intVector[1] is zero
};
```

And the same holds true for the other two vectors.  Incidentally, the `!` operator can be overidden by a class to change the behaviour.

Note also, that this is different from **C#** which requires that the expression be of a boolean type:

```
int i = 0;
if(!i) { /* compile error in C# */ }
if(i == 0) { /* ok in C# */ }
bool b = false;
if(!b) { /* ok in C# */ }
if(!(i == 0)) { /* also ok */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the important thing to know about in the statement `if (!someArray[i])` is the precedence of the operators.

first [ is evaluated, then ! is evaluated.

Writing it in a longer form might be

```
sometype a = someArray[i];
if(!a)
```